# R connecting R to twitter for sentiment analysis

Tags: r, twitter

I refered to the link given below for doing sentiment analysis
http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/text-data-mining-twitter-r/

And when I ran the code that is given below :`for (page in c(1:15)){
    # search parameter
    twitter_q <- URLencode('#prolife OR #prochoice')
    twitter_url =

```
# fetch remote URL and parse
mydata.xml <- xmlParseDoc(twitter_url, asText=F)
# extract the titles
mydata.vector <- xpathSApply(mydata.xml, '//s:entry/s:title', xmlValue, namespaces =c('s'='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'))
# aggregate new tweets with previous tweets
mydata.vectors <- c(mydata.vector, mydata.vectors)
```

}

After running the code it is prompting me for an error
Error:Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "NULL"
I/O warning : failed to load HTTP resource

I installed the packages Roath,stringr,XML,plyr which was required.And I am using R Ver 3.0.3

Kindly help me out pleas how to go about it . I am struggling for this . It would be a great help if anyone guides me properly in right direction.

Comment: You're going to want to use the [twitteR](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) and [httr](https://github.com/hadley/httr) packages instead if you really want to get the twitter data in R. Personally, I use the [t](https://github.com/sferik/t) command to dump searches (or anything else I need) from twitter into CSV format and proceed from there.

Comment: I am really new to this do u have the procedure to give the connection procedure and extract

Comment: The [twitteR](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) page shows how to setup the connection/credentials to access Twitter programmatically   and the [vignette](http://geoffjentry.hexdump.org/twitteR.pdf) [PDF] shows how to perform a search and get results.